# What is wrong with my custom authentication react-router route?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jsx, react-router-v4

Unfortunately I fail to create a custom route with [react-router version 4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/). I'm trying to construct a route which renders a component, if the user is authenticated or redirect the user to the login component in the other case.

I've been using [this documentation page](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) to get started.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({component, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => false
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}}/>}
    />
);
```

I'm using this `ProtectedRoute` like this:

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path='/' component={testComponent}/>
```

When I run this, I get the following runtime error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __rest is not defined
    at ProtectedRoute (index.tsx:19)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:305
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:304)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:279)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:187)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:236)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:703)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:522)
```

Here some more information about the stack I'm using:

- react 15.6.1
- react-router-dom 4.2.2
- typescript 2.5.2

Why is `rest` not defined? What is wrong with my custom route?

Thank you in advance!

### Update (minimal example)

A minimal example of the problem can be found [here](https://github.com/openscript/stackoverflow-react-router). To run the example follow these steps:

- Install dependencies with `yarn install`
- Run the dev server with `yarn dev`
- Go to http://localhost:8080

Comment: I have the same construction as you and it works. Could you provide a simple repo that would reproduce your problem? In your code you have differences in component spelling, you are passing `component` and using `Component`, maybe this is causing the problem.

Comment: @niba Thank you for your comment! I've updated my question and added a minimal example. You can find it here https://github.com/openscript/stackoverflow-react-router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I know what's going on. In your `tsconfig.json` you declared this rule `"noEmitHelpers": true` which tells typescript compiler to not include any helpers functions like `__rest` in your output. That's why you have runtime error with `__rest is not defined`. Changing it to `false` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixes the problem!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Typescript expert and haven't dived into TS yet, but it's definitely the issue related to your attempt to use `...rest` operator. I guess ts doesn't like spread operator within object destructuring and consequently the following structure (although it's going to work fine in ES6):

```
ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}) => {
```

If you rewrite your component with explicit usage of `path` prop it gets back to work well.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthenticated, path}) => {
    return <Route
        path={path}
        render={props => isAuthenticated
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
    />
};
```

But the fact that your code doesn't work seems strange to me, since it's mentioned that starting from 2.1 version typescript supports spread/rest within object destructuring: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest

Comment: You approach works, but I don't understand why the spread operator doesn't.